# Converting an jQuery UI widget back to original element

Tags: jquery, user-interface, widget

Like the title says - say I have a text field turned into a UI autocomplete widget, is there a way I can convert it back the original element without recreating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.autocomplete( "destroy" ) method, does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins let you do this.

It seems that autocomplete does not.

Comment: Actually I found out that it does using the .autocomplete( "destroy" ) method, problem is that I'm trying to clone a field and use .autocomplete( "destroy" ) on the new field to reassign it and this reverts both (original and clone) back to their original elements.

Comment: The clone would likely need a new ID.

Comment: @jreed121: Great, just checking :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply remove the reference to autocomplete?

```
<input id="autocompletethis" />

$("#autocompletethis").attr("id","");
```

Comment: No. The plugin may alter the field and/or make other DOM manipulations around it. You'd also want to remove event handlers.